# Determine the number of zero points of $z^8-5z^3+z-2$ within the open unit circle (Rouché?)

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

> > How many zero points does the polynomial $z^8-5z^3+z-2$ have within the open unit circle?

Hello,

consider
$$
\gamma\colon [0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{C}, \varphi\longmapsto\exp(i\varphi)
$$
and define the following functions
$$
f(z):=-5z^3,~~~~~~~~~~g(z):=z^8+z-2.
$$

This two functions are holomorphic and for all $z\in\mbox{rg}(\gamma)$ it is
$$
\lvert f(z)\rvert=5,~~~~~~~~~~\lvert g(z)\rvert\leq 4,
$$
so it is $\lvert g\rvert < \lvert f\rvert$ on $\mbox{rg}(\gamma)$.

Concerning to the theorem of Rouché the number of zero points of $f+g$ is the same as that of $f$ and this number is given by
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\, dz.
$$
It is
$$
\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{3}{z},~~~~~~~~~~\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{3}{z}\, dz=3
$$
So the given polynomial does have 3 zero points within the open unit circle.

Would be great to get a confirmation whether my result is correct.

With kindly regards!

math12

Comment: Looks good to me, the only thing I would comment on is that you are overkilling the number of roots computation. The roots of $-5z^3=0$ are.....

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but I do not understand exactly what you're objecting.

Comment: It is quite easy to find the number of zeros of $-5z^3$ inside the unit disk, and it does not require the use of the Argument Principle.

Comment: @math12 It's a fine proof. What N.S. hints at is that you can read off the number of roots (counting multiplicity) of $-5z^3$ in the unit circle directly, there's no need to compute the integral.

Comment: Oh, indeed. Thank you, you are right, it's indeed too much. I used that integral because in a previous task I had to proof that. :-)